# how can i observe iphone app about some externally changes?

Tags: iphone, sdk, observer-pattern

Hi everybody i'm new in iphone sdk developing my problem is how to observe my iphone app about some changes from something extern my app (ex: change data on server), what is the best way to observe my app about these changes? i have a solution by asking about changes using `NSTimer` every 10 sec or more but that some times will be expensive, so i'm searching about how can tell the app that the data (on a server for example) changes rather than make app ask about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can use CocoaAsyncSocket and long polling, according to [Long polling with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120606/long-polling-with-nsurlconnection)