# Server Sent Events with AFNetworking

Tags: afnetworking, server-sent-events

Has anyone managed to get Server-Sent-Events (SSE) working nicely through AFNetworking? I know AFURLConnectionOperation has an inputStream property I can attach to, but the architecture of AFNetworking seems to be oriented around receiving a response, so I'm not sure what the best way to go about it would be.

Any on how to structure such a program would be appreciated. I'm also open to other iOS libraries, if they provide cleaner solutions.

Comment: I think what you want doesn't exist as an iOS framework, except maybe ASIHTTPRequest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12940831/1445366

Comment: Yeah, I saw that question as well. The problem with ASIHTTPRequest is that it doesn't look like it's being maintained these days. I managed to put together a decently-working half-solution on top of AFNetworking, however, using NSStreams. Once I get it fully working, I'll see if I can get it into AFNetworking proper.

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I'm happy to test / code review if you want to throw it on Github.

Comment: I decided to go another way, and ended up not needing AFNetworking at all... no external dependencies. Still needs more testing and work, but worked well for my current needs. Check it out, input welcome: https://gist.github.com/elsurudo/6039065

Answer (score 2):

[AFRocketClient](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFRocketClient) (built on top of [AFNetworking 2.0](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)) contains [AFEventSource](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFRocketClient/blob/master/AFRocketClient/AFEventSource.h) which is an implementation of the W3C Event Source API.

The combination of Server Side Events and JSON Patch is being referred to as [Rocket](http://rocket.github.io).

Comment: suggested a really good solution above, I'm going to try it out now.

Comment: Is there anyone really successfully use this at all? I have big issue with the library- no event is fired after connection and it complains event source is already open.